# Informatica error - The first character in a name cannot be a number

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm getting following error:

: The first character in a name cannot be a number.

Source & Target servers are SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what it says: first character cannot be a number. A known limitation. It causes errors and unexpected behavior in different places - for example if you name a folder in the repository starting with a digit, the deployment groups will not work correctly.

Try renaming the columns just for the import. Or create another, empty table with same structrure and rename it after importing. You will probably need to use SQL overrides if you'll need to work with those columns, I'm afraid.